# How to decrease the slide down time using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my working code but I want it to slide down slowly or according to the time which I give

[**See my example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNUEx/64/)

JS:

```
$('.container a').click(function () {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
    if (!$target.hasClass('in')) $('.container .in').removeClass('in').height(0);
},
5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the below css with the time you want. The default speed is  0.35s.

```
.collapse{
-webkit-transition:height 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition:height 0.35s ease;
-o-transition:height 0.35s ease;
transition:height 0.35s ease;
}
```

**Update**

Bootstrap version 3.2.0 onward uses `.collapsing` instead of `.collapse`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gNUEx/65/)

Comment: This works well in jsfiddle but when i run the same code in local machine it will take the default speed of 0.35s.

Comment: Try giving `!important`

Comment: yeah i did but still its the same thing while it is sliding down the value changes to .35s

Comment: See if you can create a demo of what issue you are facing. Cannot replicate your issue in my fiddle.

Comment: can u just check the same thing by running it in your local machine

Comment: Working fine on my local.

Comment: Its the same code of fiddle. I can only help you if you give me a  working link of your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61479/discussion-between-karan3112-and-raghu).